# netty file upload out of memory error

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty 3.5.0 and I have implemented the upload example `HttpUploadServer`, `HttpUploadServerHandler`, `HttpUploaderServerPipeLineFactory`.

In `HttpUploadServerHandler`, there are a few commented out lines

```
// fileUpload.isInMemory();// tells if the file is in Memory
// or on File
// fileUpload.renameTo(dest); // enable to move into another
// File dest
// decoder.removeFileUploadFromClean(fileUpload); //remove
// the File of to delete file
```

When I comment-in these lines, specifically the `renameTo(dest)`, I am finding that it is failing intermittently for large file transfers, with out of memory errors seen below.

Aside: `removeFileUploadFromClean` does not seem to resolve

Can anyone tell me what is going on or how to fix?

I want to be able to transfer the large files and then move them to their final destination from the temp location. when you do not use the `renameTo`, the transfer to the temp location seems to be perfectly good but the file gets removed soon after due to clean up I presume.

```
HttpUploadServerHandler::messageReceived
HttpUploadServerHandler::messageReceived
HttpUploadServerHandler::messageReceived
HttpUploadServerHandler::messageReceived
renaming fileoxygen.exe
fileUpload.getFilename() oxygen.exe
fileUpload.getName() myfile
java.io.IOException: Map failed
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:748)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToTrustedChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:437)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:510)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.AbstractDiskHttpData.renameTo(AbstractDiskHttpData.java:292)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.MixedFileUpload.renameTo(MixedFileUpload.java:117)
at com.vayyoo.vaf.nettyapp.upload.HttpUploadServerHandler.writeHttpData(HttpUploadServerHandler.java:317)
at com.vayyoo.vaf.nettyapp.upload.HttpUploadServerHandler.readHttpDataChunkByChunk(HttpUploadServerHandler.java:253)
at com.vayyoo.vaf.nettyapp.upload.HttpUploadServerHandler.messageReceived(HttpUploadServerHandler.java:208)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.messageReceived(HttpContentEncoder.java:67)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:95)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:359)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:568)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:745)
renamed file to c:\temp\oxygen.exe
HttpUploadServerHandler::messageReceived
renaming fileoxygen.exe
fileUpload.getFilename() oxygen.exe
fileUpload.getName() myfile
... 32 more
java.io.IOException: Map failed
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:748)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToTrustedChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:437)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:510)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.AbstractDiskHttpData.renameTo(AbstractDiskHttpData.java:292)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.MixedFileUpload.renameTo(MixedFileUpload.java:117)
at com.vayyoo.vaf.nettyapp.upload.HttpUploadServerHandler.writeHttpData(HttpUploadServerHandler.java:317)
at com.vayyoo.vaf.nettyapp.upload.HttpUploadServerHandler.readHttpDataAllReceive(HttpUploadServerHandler.java:236)
at com.vayyoo.vaf.nettyapp.upload.HttpUploadServerHandler.messageReceived(HttpUploadServerHandler.java:211)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.messageReceived(HttpContentEncoder.java:67)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:95)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:359)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:568)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:745)
... 32 more
renamed file to c:\temp\oxygen.exe
HttpUploadServerHandler::messageReceived
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the destination of `renameTo()` does not belong to the same filesystem with the temporary file.  Therefore, an attempt to move the file fails and `renameTo()` copies the file to the destination and removes the temporary file.  However, it seems like `renameTo()` implemented the file copy operation in a strange way. (i.e. bug).  Until the bug is fixed, you can:

1. Specify the destination that belongs to the same partition with the temporary file directory, or
2. Get the path of the temporary file and implement the copy operation by yourself.

You can track this issue here: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/398

Answer (score 0):

The issue you present will be fixed in version 3.5.1.Final.